# jTable sorts everything as String

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable, columnsorting

I download data from MySQL (JDBC) database and display it in `jTable`:

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = (PreparedStatement) connection.prepareStatement(query); 
pstmt.setInt(1,idUser);
result = pstmt.executeQuery();

jTable.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(result));
```

I use Netbeans, on the `jTable` in properties I set `autoCreateRowSorter` option to true. Sorting works, however, some of the columns should be sorted as int value, but e.g. user ID is sorted as String.  I don't know how to initialize a table in a way that allows me to choose a column type. Then sorting should work properly. Probably it can be done in this line of code (below) that's why I'm asking for advice from someone more experienced.

```
jTable.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(result));
```

I can also add how the columns in my table look like:

```
UserID(int) / name(String) / surname(String) / phone number(int) / 
dateTime(e.g. 2018-11-03 19:02:45 - may remain in the programme as String)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, _a specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override the `getColumnClass(...)` of the `JTable` to tell the table what type of data is in each column so the table can use the appropriate render/editor and `Compartor` for each column.

Something like:

```
@Override
public Class getColumnClass(int column)
{
    for (int row = 0; row < getRowCount(); row++)
    {
        Object o = getValueAt(row, column);

        if (o != null)
        {
            return o.getClass();
        }
    }

    return Object.class;
}
```